# How convert XLS to RESX?

Tags: asp.net, excel, resx

I have an Excel file with translation and I must load a new language into the project.

How do I convert an XLS file to a RESX format?

Comment: There is [a tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19461/RESX-to-XLS-conversion-for-multi-language-support) achieving this.

Comment: Done! But program is very unusability

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio 2012, this is just as easy as selecting the excel columns to be copied over and just pasting them into resx interface that VS 2012 provides.

It works the other way around too. You could just create an xls file off of the resx by just select/copying the content from resx over into an excel document.
[image]

Comment: I've had an issue with pasting from the resx UI into Excel, where text that was valid in the RESX got seriously messed up in Excel. I seem to remember it was a CRLF in one of the columns followed some time later by a double quote. Excel then just missed out 50 rows until it found another quote. The details are woolly now, but beware.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that topic ?

[Convert CSV file or Excel spreadsheet to RESX File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223533/convert-csv-file-or-excel-spreadsheet-to-resx-file)

I think they are giving good links:

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/02/RESX-file-Web-Editor.aspx

A tool: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16068/Zeta-Resource-Editor

Answer (score 0):

This is a free tool that exports resx to xls and imports xls back to resx.
But you should have first exported to xls via this tool:
http://www.winking.be/resource-translation-helper

Answer (score -1):

- You cant try to use this `Visual Studio` extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2676967b-0516-4f5f-b312-6873e2f9d219.
- It allows to export/import your project resources to/from excel and to add new cultures.